# grep -f only gives result for the last line of the 'source' file

Tags: grep

I have a file say 'A' that has a list of items that I want to look up in say file 'B'.
All the items in file A are listed one per line and B is a tsv file with multiple items per line (some items in the line can be the ones listed in line A) I am trying to use the list in file A such that if a single line in group B has anything from any line A I want it as the output.

I did

```
grep -f A B
```

This works but only for the last line of A.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example that demonstrates the issue? What do the "items" look like - in particular, do they contain any regular expression metacharacters? Have you checked file A for trailing (or leading) whitespace or non-printing characters?

Comment: I compiled orthologues from the proteomes of 21 species. So each line in B.txt has 21 items one from each species (Sp_one1247 Sp_two1247 and son on). Now A.txt is the file of genes that I want (being more specific AT is the species header and I have a bunch of unique AT genes in file A as the list). I want to cross these two for a desired subset.

Answer (score 0):

We might need more information about which version of `grep` you have, as well as the contents of your files to answer properly with a solution, because, AFAIK, your command *should* work.

Consider these two files `a.txt` and `b.txt`:

`cat a.txt`

```
match1
match2
match3
match4
match5
```

`cat b.txt`

```
match1
match2
fail3 match3
fail4
match5
```

If we use your command, we'd expect lines 1, 2, 3, and 5 to be matched. Let's see:

`grep -f a.txt b.txt`

```
match1
match2
fail3 match3
match5
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was hoping to see but I am only getting match5. So only the last item from a.txt is being taken.

Comment: grep 3.1 (From grep --version)

Comment: I meant more along the lines of whether you were using GNU grep or not. For example, I'm using GNU grep version 3.4. Could be an unrelated problem, though - I guess others can chime in.

Comment: Oh shoot, sorry. Yep, it's GNU grep. Hmm, I guess I should try to update mine.

Comment: Could it be that the file being searched has DOS line endings? Does `grep -f A B | cat -v` show all the lines?